# How to access Google username for flutter authentication. Lit Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-signin

I'm a bit new to this, but I'm confused about how to access a user's Google username when signing in with Google.  I used Lit Firebase Auth so that basically I have to just say

```
context.signInWithGoogle();
```

But I need a display name as in my database when a user signed up with email they could enter a username, by which the text they entered would be stored and then later display as their username.

Here is my register.dart

```
try {
                        await Firebase.initializeApp();
                        UserCredential user = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                          email: _emailController.text,
                          password: _passwordController.text,
                        );
                        User updateUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
                        updateUser.updateProfile(
                            displayName: _usernameController.text);
                        userSetup(_usernameController.text);
                        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                            HomeScreen.route, (route) => false);
                      }
```

And the important part is the

```
userSetup
```

Which from my database will take that text and update the displayName.

So I guess I'm asking what to fill userSetup() instead of _usernameController.text in the case of Google sign in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out the following code for the google signing in flutter and getting credential from google and use them to firebase and the variable user contain all the user information like email, imageurl and name.

```
 GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();
    GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken, accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);

    var result = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential));
    _user = result.user;
```